# How to use "echo" in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am getting the below error when I try to run the following code:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/home/shanthi/ansible-5g/roles/ymlRoles/tasks/main.yml': line 5, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

-name: adding yml files
 shell: echo '
      ^ here
```

Here is the code:

```yaml
- name: adding yml files
  shell: echo '
         ops-center:
           product:
             autoDeploy: true
             helm:
               api:
                 release: cnee-ops-center
                 namespace: cnee
               repository:
                  url: http://engci-maven-master.cisco.com/artifactory/mobile-cnat-charts-release/builds/2019.01-5/amf.2019.01.01-5/
                  name: amf
                  ' > amf.yml
```

Comment: This actually boils down to ["How do I write correct yaml ?"](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and ["How do I correctly write yaml scalars on multiple lines"](https://yaml-multiline.info/). But once again (see answer below) don't use shell when there is an [existing module doing the job](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using the `shell` module. Instead, use the [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) module to copy a file to remote hosts.

**Contents of /path/to/local/amf.yml**

```
ops-center:
  product:
    autoDeploy: true
    helm:
      api:
        release: cnee-ops-center
        namespace: cnee
      repository:
        url: http://engci-maven-master.cisco.com/artifactory/mobile-cnat-charts-release/builds/2019.01-5/amf.2019.01.01-5/
        name: amf
```

**Playbook task**

```
- name: Copy amf.yml to host
  copy:
    src: /path/to/local/amf.yml
    dest: /path/to/remote/amf.yml
```

Comment: This still does not answer the use of "echo" in ansible as the topic question of the post.

Comment: @ColJarmen This is true, but you shouldn't use the `shell` module to create a file or put data inside it. In this case, the best practice is to use the `copy` module.